# How to get tree structure that has access rights on each node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree structure like a folder structure so with a project with nested project without a depth limit, each node has access rights on them.

Here is my graph:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (a:Account {name: "bob"})-[r:VIEWER | EDITOR]->(c:Project)

MATCH (c)<-[:IS_PARENT*]-(p)
WHERE (p)<-[:VIEWER | EDITOR]-(a)

WITH TYPE(r) as relation, p, collect(distinct c) AS children

RETURN {name: p.name, Children: [c in children | {name: c.name, access:relation}]}
```

Here is my result:

[image]

And this is what I want to get:

[image]

My problem is that the result is split in two results, and `nested child` isn't nested in `cohort`.

An other thing that is tricky is that I don't want to get a node if I don't have a relation with it.

For example here I removed the relation between `bob` and `cohort`:

[image]

So I must not get `cohort` in my result, like this:

[image]

Here is my data if you want to try:

```
MERGE (project:Project:RootProject {name: "project test"})
MERGE (child1:Project {name: "cohort"})
MERGE (child2:Project {name: "protocol"})
MERGE (child3:Project {name: "experience"})
MERGE (child4:Project {name: "nested child"})

MERGE (project)-[:IS_PARENT]->(child1)
MERGE (project)-[:IS_PARENT]->(child2)
MERGE (project)-[:IS_PARENT]->(child3)
MERGE (child1)-[:IS_PARENT]->(child4)

MERGE (bob:Account {name: "bob"})
 MERGE (bob)-[:EDITOR]->(child4)
 MERGE (bob)-[:EDITOR]->(child2)
 MERGE (bob)-[:VIEWER]->(child3)
MERGE (bob)-[:VIEWER]->(child1)
 MERGE (bob)-[:VIEWER]->(project)
```

I have tried a lot of things but I never get a good result.

Comment: Nice post. It has exp3cted result, sample query and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.  The main thing is to construct the json object as parent then grandparent projects to the root project rather than mixing both (line 10).  Notice that I removed getting VIEWER or EDITOR relationship since removing them is also faster.

```
//Get the root project from bob
MATCH (a:Account {name: "bob"})-[r]->(root:RootProject)
WITH a, root, {name:root.name, access:type(r)} as rootProject
//Get only those projects without nested parent 
MATCH (a)-[r]->(p:Project) WHERE EXISTS((p)-[:IS_PARENT]-(root))
WITH a, rootProject, p, type(r) as relations
//Get those projects with another parent (or grand parent of root project)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:IS_PARENT]->(gp:Project)<-[r]-(a)
//Collect the children and grandchildren
WITH rootProject, collect({children: {name: p.name, access:relations}, grandchild:(case when gp is null then [] else [{name:gp.name, access:type(r)}] end)}) as allChildren
RETURN {name: rootProject.name, access: rootProject.access, children: [c in allChildren]} as projects
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer it helps a lot, i have one issue, if i add a new depth it will not work.

if i add "new child" under "nested child" with a relation of EDITOR it will not show up in the response
`(cohort) -> (nested child) -> (new child)`

How can we edit your query to get the children from any depth ?

Comment: You will add another optional match similar to line 8 and add it on the collect in line 10.  Neo4j returns a response on a fixed json format so if you want it to be flexible, you may need to use another layer like java or python to do the formatting. Java or python will call your neo4j query and format the data the way you want.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, please vote/accept it. thanks.

Comment: Ok see, so this is not scalable for a undetermined depth like 100 nested children ?

Answer (score 0):

It may not meet your expectation, but how about this for scalability?

```
MATCH (a:Account {name: "bob"})-[r:VIEWER|EDITOR]->(c:Project)

MATCH path=(p)-[:IS_PARENT*]->(c)
WHERE (p)<-[:VIEWER | EDITOR]-(a)

WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths, false, {
  nodes: {Project: ['name']},
  rels:  {IS_PARENT: ['name']}
}) YIELD value
RETURN value
```